# Do we have examples of Roman freedmen becoming wealthy?

Tags: ancient-rome, slavery

I was curious to know more about this, found on Wikipedia:

"Other freedmen became wealthy. The brothers who owned House of the Vettii, one of the biggest and most magnificent houses in Pompeii, are thought to have been freedmen. A freedman designed the amphitheater in Pompeii."

Do we have some other examples of freed slaves becoming rich?

Comment: Unfortunately this becomes a list question, with everyone adding a different example. No conclusive answer.

Comment: The only conclusive albeit unsatisfactory answer would be: yes, plenty.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search found [this article](http://www.ancient.eu/article/629/), which mentions the freedman C. Caecilius Isidorus (who would eventually own over 4,000 slaves himself). I'm sure a slightly longer search would find many more.